# Drupal commerce - validating coupon against product programatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, coupon, commerce

All my products are related to some "Magazine" content type objects - that is every product has node reference to Magazine object. Also, I added same node reference field to coupon, referencing again to nodes of "Magazine" content types. What I want to achieve is to have coupons that will work only with some Magazines. That is if coupon Magazine matches product Magazine coupon is valid. Other way it's not. I can't do that with rules because I can not approach that product's Magazine field any way. All I can see is line items and I can't go further to products. I was hoping that I can do that from code. Is there a way to programmatically set if some coupon is valid or not.

I just want to go trough all line items and check if some of them has the same Magazine set like coupon does.

I'm also wondering does it makes sense at all to relate coupon with single product/line item or not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I follow this explanation but if it is a product line item you should be able to access the product id, and load the product and check against the valid magazines.

Alternatively, what you could do is add a field to your coupon type for the allowed magazines with an entity reference field to the magazine nodes/products. Then either by code or through rules, check against the line item's product to the list of acceptable magazines for that particular coupon. Call this code either through your own validation or calculation method. ie. you could create either a custom coupon in code or you could add a rule to validate a coupon of type "magazine coupon" and in the rule call some custom php code.

```
// ** note: this is totally untested/rough code **
// Just to give you an idea of how it *could* work 

// assuming we have a $coupon and a $line_item at this point 

// some basic set up
$coupon_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_coupon', $coupon);
$line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);

$product_id = $line_item_wrapper->product_id->raw();
$product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
$product_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', $product);

$magazine_id = $product_wrapper->magazine->nid->raw();
$eligible_magazines = $coupon_wrapper->coupon_magazines->value();

// for each eligible product on the list from the coupon
for($i = 0; $i < count($eligible_products); $i++) {   

    // compare our product's magazine value to the eligible magazine id
    if($eligible_magazines[$i]->nid  == $magazine_id) {
        // do stuff here, whether return true for the validation etc
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you only have the order, you can do something very similar and loop through the line items on the order. The order just has IDs I believe so you would have to use commerce_line_item_load function.

To answer your question in the comments - 
Yes you could either add a hook to do this code in a module or you could create a rule to do so. – You could add a validation rule for your coupon something  like

(again untested)

```
{ "rules_coupon_check_magazine" : {
    "LABEL" : "Coupon: Check Magazine",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "php", "commerce_coupon" ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_coupon_validate" ],
    "IF" : [
      {"entity_has_field" : {
      "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ],
      "field" : "commerce_coupon_order_reference"
    }
  },
  { "NOT data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-coupon-order-reference" ] } },
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "\/\/ my validation code here - either return true or false\r\nreturn true;" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : {
          "message" : "Sorry, you cannot apply this coupon to the order",
          "type" : "error"
        }
      },
      { "commerce_coupon_action_is_invalid_coupon" : [] }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kimberly for your code and advices. But thing is I don't know where to put that code? Is there some hook function or something? And when I detect that coupon is not valid what should I do? How can I invalidate it for that order only.

Comment: By following rules logic I expect that there should be some coupon hook action where you get coupon and order and do something to that coupon reference...or return true-false...or something. I think I even found that function, but it's not hook. I need a hook function where I can enter my code - don't want to change module code.

Comment: http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce_coupon!commerce_coupon.api.php/group/commerce_coupon_api_hooks/DC

Where are hook functions? Am I looking at wrong place maybe?

Comment: I should hook this function I guess:
http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce_coupon!commerce_coupon.module/function/commerce_coupon_code_is_valid/7

Comment: Yes you could either add a hook to do this code in a module or you could create a rule to do so.

Comment: I've "patched" that function I mentioned above and it works well. Thanks for your help.